# Apache connection timeout

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, timeout, connection

I recently developed a site using codeigniter. The site is working fine and the ci profiler shows the following (for a random controller)

Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0039
Controller Execution Time ( Test / Index )      0.0152
Total Execution Time    0.0192

Database queries QUERIES: 6 (0.0079 seconds)
Memory usage : 2,891,752 bytes

However, the site is experiencing high peak usage at certain times (in relation to world cup football matches). It's not actually that high (about 60-70 simultaneous users) but the server gets very slow (up to 20s to load a page) and eventually times out.

The site is hosted on an OVH dedicated server under https:
Serveur EG-64 - E5-1650v3 - 64GB - SoftRaid 2x4To.
Bande passante Connexion réseau 1 Gbps; BP OVH/OVH 500 Mbps; BP sortante 500 Mbps; BP entrante 500 Mbps.

It actually takes up to 20s to load the index.php file of CI (debug log created on first line of index.php), once loaded the pages are displayed fast. It's the connection that takes time.

Any idea where to start looking ?

Comment: The CodeIgniter times look acceptable so your best bet is probably fine-tuning apache. Whichever it is, try a Google search for "optimizing apache". Your hardware looks more than capable of handling the load you mention.

Comment: In particular, find out which Multi-Processing Module (MPM) your Apache setup is using.

Comment: Thanks you were right, tweaking the httpd.conf (max threads) made it work. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -2):

Fixed by tweaking the apache httpd.conf

Comment: Can you share the fix?